# Add $_POST to array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have 1 array:

```
$meta_array = array(
   'lot',
   'floor',
   'block'
);
```

How can I convert the above array to show

```
'lot' => $_POST['lot'], 'floor' => $_POST['floor']
```

so I can `update_post_meta($new, 'number' , $meta_array)` like this.
I am trying to save some KBs as my form php size is getting rather large.

Thank you for your advice.

FINALLY - I DID THIS

```
        $new_meta = array();
        foreach($meta_array as $val){
            if (isset($_POST[$val])) {
                $new_meta[$val] = sanitize_array_text_field($_POST[$val]);
            }
        }
        update_post_meta($new, 'property', $new_meta);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `foreach` loop:

```
$meta_array = array('lot', 'floor', 'block');
$another_array = array();
foreach($meta_array as $val){
    $another_array[$val] = $_POST[$val];
}
```

Comment: I tried this but didnt work. Any idea why?
    $new_meta = array();
    foreach($meta_array as $val){
        $new_meta[$val] = $_POST[$val];
    }
    update_post_meta($new, 'property' , $new_meta);

Comment: What didn’t work? What did you expect and what happened instead?

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
$posted = array_combine ($meta_array, $_POST);
```

You will get :

```
Array(
   [lot]   => $_POST['lot'],
   [floor] => $_POST['floor'],
   [block] => $_POST['block']
)
```

Comment: Great answer, but i needed to sanitize the field and add isset. Please see my update. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
if(isset($_POST['lot']))
    $meta_array['lot'] = $_POST['lot'];
if(isset($_POST['floor']))
    $meta_array['floor'] = $_POST['floor'];
if(isset($_POST['block']))
    $meta_array['block'] = $_POST['block'];
```

Using isset() is a little safer.

Comment: Yes, i have issue with the index error, but i managed to add some code, please see my update above. Thanks!